# Absolute path doesn't work in webpack 2

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I have been trying to get absolute paths work with webpack 2 in my angular 2 project. I used [this](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter) as my boilerplate code. And to make it work with absolute path I tried the following in `webpack.config.ts`:

```
config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('./src'), 'node_modules']
  };
```

And in `webpack.d.ts`:

```
resolve?: {
    extensions?: Array<string>;
    modules?: Array<string>;
  };
```

But when I try `import {AppComponent} from 'app/app.component'` it doesn't work, it errors out with `Cannot find module 'app/app.component'...`
I can't figure out what is causing this. Please help.

P.S. I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/issues/308). But couldn't get it to work.

**EDIT 1**

Please find my try to make this work [here](https://github.com/dsasidhar/angular-webpack2-starter), `https://github.com/dsasidhar/angular-webpack2-starter`

Comment: Check : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4874

Comment: @RameshRajendran I don't understand, my issue is not with typings. The typings work just fine. It is the import that doesn't seem to work when giving absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack Typescript loader resolves module paths considering the `tsconfig`. So you have to add this line to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"baseUrl": "./src" // Or whatever is your root
```

If you have a `tsconfig.app.json` inside the `src` folder, you should also specify a `baseUrl` there. I suggest not having more than one `tsconfig` file as tool support for that is not very well.

More information on Typescript module resolution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). Check out Base URL and Path Mapping sections.

Comment: Please see my edit, I have tried this and I couldn't get it work.

Comment: @sasidhar It certainly works after moving `baseUrl` into `compilerOptions` :)

Comment: @sasidhar Just make sure it also works in all dev, prod and aot builds. Sometimes it works in one but doesn't work on others depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you could use **path.join** with **__dirname** variable

```
config.resolve = {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src') , 'node_modules']
  };
```

**Note:**

`path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` will also work

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I also logged the result of `path.join` the path is correct.
P.S: `path.resolve` should work as good as `path.join`, I don't understand the point of this answer.

Comment: adding __dirname before src might resolve the path problem. That is how it is resolved in ng6 starter https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js. the answer is not about path.join or path.resolve but usage of __dirname

Comment: I have tried using __dirname, this solution doesn't work, like I said the returned path is right even when I use `'./src'`.